# How can i add HashMap fields to firestore and get back the results using the lastest JetpackCompose way

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Trying to add nested HashMap objects to firestore.[Project Source from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLOX.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgLOX.png): https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8 by Alex Mamo
I was trying this way as it is a MVVM project adding the new features i don't know this correct or wrong please correct me if wrong

data class

```
data class Book(
var id: String? = null,
var title: String? = null,
var author: String? = null,
val book_parts:HashMap<String,String>? = null)
```

Repository

```
typealias Books = List<Book>
typealias BooksResponse = Response<Books>
typealias AddBookResponse = Response<Boolean>
typealias DeleteBookResponse = Response<Boolean>

interface BooksRepository {
fun getBooksFromFirestore(): Flow<BooksResponse>

suspend fun addBookToFirestore(title: String, author:String, book_parts: HashMap<String,String> ) : AddBookResponse

suspend fun deleteBookFromFirestore(bookId: String): DeleteBookResponse}
```

RepositoryImpl

```
@Singleton
class BooksRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val booksRef: CollectionReference
) : BooksRepository {
override fun getBooksFromFirestore() = callbackFlow {
    val snapshotListener = booksRef.orderBy(TITLE).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
        val booksResponse = if (snapshot != null) {
            val books = snapshot.toObjects(Book::class.java)
            Response.Success(books)
        } else {
            Response.Failure(e)
        }
        trySend(booksResponse).isSuccess
    }
    awaitClose {
        snapshotListener.remove()
    }
}

override suspend fun addBookToFirestore(
    title: String,
    author: String,
    book_parts: HashMap<String, String>
): AddBookResponse {
    return try {
        val id = booksRef.document().id
        val book = Book(
            id = id,
            title = title,
            author = author,
            book_parts = book_parts
        )
        booksRef.document(id).set(book).await()
        Response.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Response.Failure(e)
    }
}

override suspend fun deleteBookFromFirestore(bookId: String): DeleteBookResponse {
    return try {
        booksRef.document(bookId).delete().await()
        Response.Success(true)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Response.Failure(e)
    }
}}
```

UseCases

```
class AddBook(private val repo: BooksRepository) {

suspend operator fun invoke(
    title: String,
    author: String,
    book_parts: HashMap<String,String>
) = repo.addBookToFirestore(title, author,book_parts)}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class BooksViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val useCases: UseCases
): ViewModel(){
var booksResponse by mutableStateOf<BooksResponse>(Response.Loading)
private set
var addBooksResponse by mutableStateOf<AddBookResponse>(Response.Success(false))
private set
var deleteBookResponse by mutableStateOf<DeleteBookResponse>(Response.Success(false))
private set
var openDialog by mutableStateOf(false)
private set

init {
    getBooks()
}

private fun getBooks() = viewModelScope.launch {
   useCases.getBooks().collect { response ->
       booksResponse = response
   }
}

fun addBook(title: String, author: String, book_parts: HashMap<String,String>) = viewModelScope.launch {
    addBooksResponse = Response.Loading
    addBooksResponse = useCases.addBook(title, author,book_parts)
}

fun deleteBook(bookId: String) = viewModelScope.launch {
    deleteBookResponse = Response.Loading
    deleteBookResponse = useCases.deleteBook(bookId)
}

fun openDialog(){
    openDialog = true
}

fun closeDialog(){
    openDialog = false
}
```

}

With composable how to add it to the screen and display the nested objects

BooksScreen

```
@Composable
fun BooksScreen(
viewModel: BooksViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopBar()
    },
    content = { padding ->
        Books(
            booksContent = { books ->
                BooksContent(
                    padding = padding,
                    books = books,
                    deleteBook = { bookId ->
                        viewModel.deleteBook(bookId)
                    }
                )
                AddBookAlertDialog(
                    openDialog = viewModel.openDialog,
                    closeDialog = {
                        viewModel.closeDialog()
                    },
                    addBook = { title, author, book_parts ->
                        viewModel.addBook(title, author , book_parts)
                    }
                )

            }
        )
    },
    floatingActionButton = {
        AddBookFloatingButton(
            openDialog = {
                viewModel.openDialog()
            }
        )
    }
)
AddBook()
DeleteBook()
```

}

AddBookAlertDialog

```
@Composable
fun AddBookAlertDialog(
openDialog: Boolean,
closeDialog: () -> Unit,
addBook: (title: String, author: String, book_parts: HashMap<String, String>) -> Unit
) {
if (openDialog) {
    var title by remember { mutableStateOf(NO_VALUE) }
    var author by remember { mutableStateOf(NO_VALUE) }
    var book_parts by remember { mutableMapOf<String,String>() }
    val focusRequester = FocusRequester()

    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = closeDialog,
        title = {
            Text(
                text = ADD_BOOK
            )
        },
        text = {
            Column {
                TextField(
                    value = title,
                    onValueChange = { title = it },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            text = BOOK_TITLE
                        )
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
                )
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    coroutineContext.job.invokeOnCompletion {
                        focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    }
                }
                Spacer(
                    modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)
                )
                TextField(
                    value = author,
                    onValueChange = { author = it },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text(
                            text = AUTHOR
                        )
                    }
                )
        FloatingActionButton(onClick = {  }) {
                 
                    Icon(Icons.Default.Add, "")
                }
            }
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    closeDialog()
                    addBook(title, author)
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = ADD
                )
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = closeDialog
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = DISMISS
                )
            }
        }
    )
}}
```

BookCard

```
@Composable
fun BookCard(
book: Book, deleteBook: () -> Unit
) {
Card(
    shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(
            start = 8.dp, end = 8.dp, top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp
        )
        .clickable { }
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    elevation = 3.dp,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(12.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Column {
            TextTitle(
                bookTitle = book.title ?: NO_VALUE
            )
            TextAuthor(bookAuthor = book.author ?: NO_VALUE)
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        DeleteIcon(
            deleteBook = deleteBook
        )
        EditBook()
    }}
```

I don't know how to add the mutable way of hashMap and to get back the nested objects with compose way and sorry for the multiple files as it a MVVM

Trying for this
[image]

I wanted to add the book_parts column dynamically like this
[image]

Comment: Hey Shiva. Where exactly in your code are you populating the `book_parts` with data?

Comment: Hey @AlexMamo I trying to add it dynamic way so that each book has it different hash maps but i am new to jetpack compose i tried it in this way " var textFieldCount by remember { mutableStateOf (1) }
        repeat(textFieldCount)" So onClick it should add a new Textfield everytime

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I was referring to how to add that data under a book, for example, how did you add `PS-1` and `PS-2` under `book_parts`?

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding that's just a hardcoded in firestore i eventually wanted that way as an example

Comment: So you want to add such data not from the console but from code, right?

Comment: yes i wanted to add in the compose way Thanks and by the way waiting for your next course @AlexMamo shopping App thanks for the teaching sir

Comment: You're welcome, Shiva. But please answer my latest comment.

Comment: yes i wanted in code to add it

Comment: To be able to help, we need to see what you have already tried, and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: with MVVM architecture i  tried adding it in model class repository and usescases and finally in the UI thing How to deal with HashMap to make it mutable i couldn't solve it

Comment: Add that data directly into the HashMap using something like `data.put("PS-1" to "Volume1")`. That's why I asked because I couldn't see that in code. Give it a try and tell us if it works.